# Set Boundaries For A PictureBox In C# Windows Form

Tags: c#

so we are tasked to do a bomberman game using C# but we are not allowed to use other ide except for Visual studio using windows form. We are not allowed to use unity too. so my problem is how can i set boundaries? so that the player wont pass through the tiles... Please take time to check the image:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Layout
{
    public partial class FormView : Form
    {
        enum Position
        {
            Left, Right, Up, Down
        }

        private int _x;
        private int _y;
        private Position _objPosition;

        public FormView()
        {
            _x = 50;
            _y = 50;
            _objPosition = Position.Down;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormView_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap("Character.png"), _x, _y, 50, 50);
        }

        private void tmrMoving_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void FormView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                _x += 50;
                _objPosition = Position.Right;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                _x -= 50;
                _objPosition = Position.Left;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            {
                _y -= 50;
                _objPosition = Position.Up;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                _y += 50;
                _objPosition = Position.Down;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to keep a map in memory and test the next postion against it to see if it would be allowed.

Comment: Nobody suggested to use a DBMS.

Comment: how could that happen? can you give me a sample code?

Comment: i am sorry i really don't have enough knowledge when it comes to programming a game using a windows form in visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `_objPosition` as I understand it contains the location (x,y) of your person then just check that against the size of the PictureBox with an `If` statement. I'm not sure what the `_objPosition` contains, you could just use  your `x` and `y` directly as well.

```
        var _x = 0;
        var _y = 0;
        if (_x == pictureBox1.Width)
        {
            // Dont Move
        }
        else
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.D:
                    _x += 50;
                    _objPosition = Position.Right;
                    break;
                case Keys.A:
                    _x -= 50;
                    _objPosition = Position.Left;
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (_y == pictureBox1.Length)
        {
            //Don't Move
        }
        else
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.W:
                    _y -= 50;
                    _objPosition = Position.Up;
                    break;
                case Keys.S:
                    _y += 50;
                    _objPosition = Position.Down;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

*Edited to push you more in the right direction.*

Comment: yea that is my decision plan but i don't know what to put inside those code blocks

Comment: I edited the code above to do what I think you want, this should at least push you in the right direction. You can still you the `if` statements if you want, I just think the `switch` is cleaner.

Comment: thanks for the big help... but i am not yet familiar to C# syntax and i am still getting to know stuffs... cramming hits

Comment: Sure thing, if that works for you please mark this as the answer!

Comment: frank can i ask for your email?

Comment: i got some questions hahaha